# Clementine won't load ubuntu theme

Tags: clementine

In Ubuntu 14.04, Clementine has a ugly theme because is not loading the correct Ubuntu theme.

I have the 64 bits installation. I know the bug with Skype and I already installed Murrine engine gtk2 and other GTK2 engine. In Skype is fixed but in Clementine the problem continues

[image: clementine]

Comment: Is Skype also having the same issue? is this a 64bit install? Please edit iyour questions, don't answer in hte comments.

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been resolved in clementine 1.2.3 update.
Update by

`$ wget github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/releases/download/1.2.3/clementine_1.2.3.trusty_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i clementine_1.2.3.trusty_amd64.deb`